# Multiple Column Selcet in Sqlite In One Query Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have table with huge data (approximately 330 MB). When app search from the data it produced results very late. I am selecting just one column but it is also very slow. I have noticed that if I make a new table with that specific column then search results are fast. Tables structure is below.

AllData (table with huge data)

```
id    |  UName    |  details
1     |  ارشد    |  long text
2     |  احمد    |  long text
```

SearchTable

```
id   |  LatinNames
1    |  Arshad
2    |  Ahmad
```

I want to let the user search by LatinNames from SearchTable and select UName From AllData.
Both tables have same ids so if we can search from SearchTable and then Select specific ids from AllData this will do the job.

Comment: Did you try a simple JOIN? What did you try? What is not working? What is the question here?

Comment: I want to  search by LatinNames from SearchTable and select UName From AllData. And what is join?

Comment: Ok. I can understand what you want. But what did you try? What problems are you having?

Comment: I did not try any thing yet. Just doing performance tests and asked the question. From user comment I came to know that there is some thing Join in sql. I am very new in this actually.

Comment: Then I suggest you start with a good SQL tutorial. JOINs are really the ABC of SQL. Stack Overflow is not used for these types of questions. Read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a name from AllDate but you have a LatinNames (that I think is want you are asking) you need a subselect.

```
select UName from AllData
where id= (select id from SearchTable where LatinNames ="Ahmad")
```

Comment: A subselect? How about a JOIN?

Comment: It should be the best option, but obviously he does not have too much knowledge of SQL and this can be easiest to undestand.